# Passport JS failing to retrieve User

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

Below is my registration strategy in passportJS. Most of the code runs fine until right at the bottom where I go to res.send the user argument after the passport.authenticate method has successfully authenticated the strategy. However whenever I am sent back the response I receive a page with a "false" message. Instead of sending me the users details I am sent "false" instead.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  return done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use("registerUser",
  new LocalStrategy({ passReqToCallback: true },
    function(req, username, password, done) {
      var newUser = new User({
        name: username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: password
      });

      newUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        return done(null, newUser);
      });
    }));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", { title: "Register!", url: req.url });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("registerUser", function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    res.send(user);
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Does `newUser` look like what you expect before calling `done` in the strategy callback?

Comment: Yeah the schema is the same

Answer (score 0):

You should use `passport.authenticate()` as a second argument before `function(req, res)`:

```
`app.post('/', passport.authenticate('registerUser', function(err, user) {
  if (err) return done(err);
  if (!user) return done(null, false);
  done(null, user);
```

}), function(req, res) {
      res.send(user);
  });`

This way you introduced authentication middleware that will run before the response. Have a look here: https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js

Comment: You can't output the user object because the new function of which you believe I should create is outside the scope of the function with the user argument in it and therefore I will not be able to access it

Comment: @animsaj The route handler is correct, it's just using [a custom callback](http://passportjs.org/docs/#custom-callback)